# Injecting Annotated Bean into Regular Bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

AppContext.xml

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.myapp.MyClass">
    <property ref="myService"/>
</bean>
```

MyService.java

```
@Service
public class MyService {
 ...
}
```

This will throw an exception stating that no bean can be found for property "myService", which I understand because it can't be found in the context files, but I can autowire that field in other spring managed beans, but I need to explicitly build the bean in my context because the POJO is not editable in the scope of my project.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're already using the component classpath scanning, then you can give an explicit name to the component, rather than letting Spring auto-generate a name for you:

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyService {
 ...
}
```

I haven't tested this, but I believe this is the case.

---

**edit**: After a bit of digging, the logic for determining the bean name is found in `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName()`.:

```
public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    if (definition instanceof AnnotatedBeanDefinition) {
        String beanName = determineBeanNameFromAnnotation((AnnotatedBeanDefinition) definition);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(beanName)) {
            // Explicit bean name found.
            return beanName;
        }
    }
    // Fallback: generate a unique default bean name.
    return buildDefaultBeanName(definition);
}
```

In other words, it tries to get an explicit bean name from the annotation(s), and failing that, it uses the default:

```
protected String buildDefaultBeanName(BeanDefinition definition) {
    String shortClassName = ClassUtils.getShortName(definition.getBeanClassName());
    return Introspector.decapitalize(shortClassName);
}
```

So yes, for an annotated class called `MyService`, the auto-generated bean name should indeed be `myService`, so your code should work.

Out of curiosity, what happens when you use `@Component` instead of `@Service`?

Comment: won't the auto-generated name be the lower-case name of the class?

Comment: @Bozho: I don't think so, no. When you use `<bean class="A.B">` with no `id`, the auto-generated name is something like `B#0`, and I assume the same applies to the auto-scanned components.

Comment: it's not the same scenario, because there can't be another annotated bean of the same class

Answer (score 1):

This should work, if you have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.root.package" />
```

Comment: I've gotten things to work, but I'm not exactly sure how, I'll have to spend a bit more time investigating, but I will come back to this and choose and answer soon